# "inactive" submit button until you click on one of the radio buttons

Tags: java, jquery, css, forms, radio-button

I want the submit button to be "inactive" until you click on one of the radio buttons in the form, the button will then change the background image from button.png to button_active.png after you've clicked.

Can this be done with only CSS? or do I have to involve jquery / javascript? 
how do i do this?

```
<input id="1" type="radio" name="1" value="1" />
<input id="2" type="radio" name="2" value="2" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="valj"  />
```

Comment: You should make an attempt yourself first and then come back with any specific issues you run into.

Answer (score 8):

You can start with the submit button being disabled:

```
<input id="1" type="radio" name="1" value="1" />
<input id="2" type="radio" name="2" value="2" />
<input type="submit" disabled name="submit" value="valj"  />
```

Then using script bind to the change event of the radio buttons and inspect their values and remove the disabled attribute when required, similar to this:

```
// cache reference to all radio buttons.
var $radioButtons = $("input:radio");

$radioButtons.change(function(){
    var anyRadioButtonHasValue = false;

    // iterate through all radio buttons
    $radioButtons.each(function(){
        if(this.checked){
            // indicate we found a radio button which has a value
            anyRadioButtonHasValue = true;

            // break out of each loop
            return false;
        }
    });

    // check if we found any radio button which has a value
    if(anyRadioButtonHasValue){
        // enable submit button.
        $("input[name='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else{
        // else is kind of redundant unless you somehow can clear the radio button value
        $("input[name='submit']").attr("disabled", "");
    }
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zSfhZ/) - Enable button if any radio button is selected.

---

Comment: +1 for providing an unobtrusive solution.

Comment: Thanks for providing iteration function to check through all the radioButtons.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the button disabled, then enable it if one of the radio buttons is selected.

```
<input id="1" type="radio" name="1" value="1" onClick="document.getElementById('subutton').disabled = false" />
<input id="2" type="radio" name="2" value="2" onClick="document.getElementById('subutton').disabled = false" />
<input id="subutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="valj" disabled/>
```

Comment: nope, it's not working, it disable the button alright, but its not active when i click on the radio button. isnt there anyway to just add a css class to the button when click?

Comment: It does work, because I've tested it. Make sure that the ID matches properly. And no, you cant add a CSS class to the button when the radio button is selected

Comment: `And no, you cant add a CSS class to the button when the radio button is selected`....jQuery `addClass()` on change/click event? OP is open to a cross-browser jQuery solution.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: I'm pretty sure by how he said it in the question that he was after a *CSS only* solution if possible, and then if not resort to JS.